# How to maintain order after matching?

Tags: r, dataframe

Using igraph, I built a network from an edge list from which I extract nodes (vertices) with:

```
V(g)$name
[1] "Molecule"    "CSS"         "Scaffold"    "Fragment"    "CFramework"  "RScaffold"   "BTFramework" "Ph4G"
```

In a separate table I have some frequencies

```
> nodes
  N        name
1 37021         CSS
2  2506    Scaffold
3 13809        Ph4G
4   846  CFramework
5  4835   RScaffold
6 23388    Fragment
7  1401 BTFramework
8  1857    Molecule
```

I would like the set the node size according to these frequencies. The match function returns the correspondance between the node list and the frequency table, but unfortunately the order in the output is not the same as in the node list.

```
size = nodes[with(nodes, match(name, V(g)$name, nomatch = FALSE)), 1]
V(g)$size = (log(size)+1)
```

Is there a way to maintain the order in size as it is in V(g)$name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `size <- nodes$N[match(V(g)$name, nodes$name)]`.